# Odd (possibly) gnu-efi specific data type `UINTN`

Tags: c, gnu-efi

I found a really odd data type I've never seen before in some GNU EFI code, specifically a call to `GetMemoryMap`, wherein the map size, the map key, and the descriptor size are all declared to be the type `UINTN`. My IDE does not recognize this data type, so I assume this is something specific to GNU EFI.

I've tried Googling around for it, but all I get is completely irrelevant results or specifications talking about `uint_[number of bits]_t` (and similar) types.

The code I'm talking about:

```
UINTN mapSize = 0, mapKey, descriptorSize;
EFI_MEMORY_DESCRIPTOR *memoryMap = NULL;
UINT32 descriptorVersion;
// Get the required memory pool size for the memory map
Status = uefi_call_wrapper(BS->GetMemoryMap, 5, &mapSize, memoryMap, NULL, &descriptorSize, NULL);
if(Status != EFI_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL) { return Status; }
```

Comment: Described in the [docs](https://edk2-docs.gitbook.io/edk-ii-c-coding-standards-specification/5_source_files/56_declarations_and_types)

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Ah. For some reason my Google searches didn't turn up that.

Comment: I did a quick Google using `"UINTN" UEFI` and [the UEFI Spec](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI%20Spec%202_6.pdf) occurred. It's in *2.3.1 Data Types* of the spec.